# An effective way to find missing minterms

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I've been messing with logic formulas lately and there was one thing that was often causing me headache. I'll describe it briefly.

When using Quine-McClausky's algorithm for finding MDNF and MCNF, I often have to find both for one formula. Consider this:

ABC or ~AB~C or ~ABC or AB~C

Before I say anything else, let me clarify: ABC = A and B and C; ~C = not C.

Obviously, for such a short formula with only 3 variables, it easy to find the remaining minterms. But, what when you have 5 or 6 variables? I am quite bad at visualizing things, thus I often have to draw a truth table to deduct what minters are missing.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Logic Friday](http://www.sontrak.com/) for such tasks.
It includes [Espresso](http://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/pubs/downloads/espresso/), a tool to minimize two-level *Boolean* functions.

The [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) does not guarantee optimal solutions. It is merging adjacent minterms in a greedy fashion, whereas *Espresso* has an *exact mode* option which will end with the minimum number of terms. In general, there is no polynomial method known to compute a minimal minterm cover for arbitrary Boolean functions. The NP-complete complexity of the `Min-DNF` problem is discussed [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Papers/mindnf.pdf).

For small expressions, you could also [ask WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A%20and%20B%20and%20C%29%20or%20%28not%20A%20and%20B%20and%20not%20C%29%20or%20%28not%20A%20and%20B%20and%20C%29%20or%20%28A%20and%20B%20and%20not%20C%29).